# How to differentiate critical windows updates among all updates in c++

Tags: c++, windows, updates

How to differentiate critical windows updates among all updates in C++?

Added from his answer:

I'll formulate the question differently. How to find out the Level of Iupdate. In vista levels are important, recommended, optional in xp they are high-priorit, Optional. I want to write a c++ program to count say available important updates.

Shushanik

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write a program to automatically choose whether or not apply Windows security updates. Am I right?

Comment: Voted to close. Merely adding the words "in C++" doesn't make this a programming question. The real question is how to determine at all, and that's not programming. Similarly: "How to achieve World Peace in Java?"

Comment: Just use the C++ Standard Library function `bool std::how_to_differentiate_critical<windows_update>::is_critical(windows_update* w)`. You have to include `<omnipotent>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as how can you determine heuristically that one update is critical and the other is non-critical?...this is where a human steps in to check and determine from another source such as the Knowledge-base to base the decision on that.

Similar to captcha, you cannot kid or fool them automatically...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: @UncleBens: maybe...but...it would be remiss to ignore the non-critical...but how do you know? the non-critical may boost performance or patch an exploit...?!? what you think?

Comment: @t0mm13b normally if something us running you don't care if it gets faster if it might break compatibility. But you still want to install the critical ones as those fix things that might break and vulnerabilities. (Think about embedded computers running windows such as osciloscopes).

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN forums have an answer for you: [How to use WSUS API by C++?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/2553a5a3-baa9-453a-908b-abb5f4136632)

And MSDN of course: [Windows Server Update Services 3.0 Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms744624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)